# Why are my TensorBoard training plots incomplete (using Jupyter/TensorFlow/Keras)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

When I use TensorBoard to visualise the error over the training set and validation set the training set error series in TensorBoard often stops early (not showing all steps).

When using the following code the series stops at a random step:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

# Generate some training data (Y = X0 - X2^2).
X = np.random.rand(1000,2)
Y = X[:,0] + np.square(X[:,1])
X_val = np.random.rand(100,2)
Y_val = X_val[:,0] + np.square(X_val[:,1])

# Tensorboard logs.
log_dir = os.path.join('./tensorboard-logs/', 'stack-overflow', time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S'))
os.makedirs(log_dir, exist_ok=True)
tb_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

# Tensorflow model (create, compile, train)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=X[0].shape),
                             keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=True, activation='linear')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
hist = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=1000, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), verbose=0, callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

When I plot the `hist` object I get the plot I expect -- two series with values from 0 to 499:

```
# Plot history locally.
plt.plot(range(len(hist.history['mse'])), hist.history['mse'], 'r')
plt.plot(range(len(hist.history['val_mse'])), hist.history['val_mse'], 'b')
plt.figure()
```

The code above results in a full plot. However, if I look at what TensorBoard shows me the training plot often stops well before value 499. Any ideas why the TensorBoard training plot is often incomplete?

Answer (score 2):

As per usual, after battling with this problem for most of the day I think I found the answer just minutes after posting: just add the `--reload_multifile` to the tensorboard command.